# What to do when there is a job lined up in 4 days but I haven't decided where I want to work yet

Tags: united-states, fresher, multiple-jobs

I accepted two offers A and B at the same time and worked at A since A started earlier, asking B to delay the start day by 1 month so that I have more time to evaluate the pros and cons between the two, and also to get some paychecks and avoid visa restrictions for unemployment time.

Now, I have only two more days to tell my boss I quit/decide if I want to work for B, and I’m still dead stuck about my decision.

I’m not really satisfied with A.

- Annual pay is $20K less.
- Job A is 20 miles away from my relatives and I’m living rent-free with them.
- I’m the only developer there and have been struggling with projects alone & my supervisor doesn’t have enough coding skills to mentor me since most legacy code is outsourced, and there’s no document -> Almost no space to learn and grow.
- Burnt out with the 2-hour commute daily.
- The pros are that I’m not lonely; it’s a fun metropolitan; it’s better financially.

Job B is more systematic with the onboarding process (saw their plans, quality unknown), better benefits, bigger IT team. I have to pay rent and utilities, but B’s in a cheaper area.

**Editted my questions:**
All of that aside, how to make better decisions (and quicker) when considering 2 offers in such a short time frame? Any criteria I should also consider aside from the *cost of living, training process, neighborhood, and available connections*? I’ve made a list of pros and cons based on those parameters. Intend to ask my boss for a performance evaluation, if it’s not good and he wants something I can’t provide, that’s more reason for me to quit.
**End edit**

My concerns are my fear of struggling again in a new job, and lack of a support system when relocating, and of course the difficult awkward talk I will have with my boss if quitting

Risk management wise:

- If I quit, can job A sue me or do anything to me if I leave on
  extremely short notice? Will it affect my career (I don’t plan to put
  it on my resume if I quit after a few months, but background checks
  can find out)?
- If I stay, what should I do with B since I delayed one
  month already? That will leave a bad reputation?
- Are there any other (legal) risks overall? The worst-case scenario is I lose both jobs. I know words fly around.

Being a fresh grad with no internships and little tech experience, the opportunity to learn, be mentored, and work in a team is important to me.
Pardon my English, panic, the unwise course of action I took, and the extremely rush time. I'm also trying not to ask for advice here although tempted to, but for evaluations of legal risks, rational actions, etc.

Edit: Clarify my question about the criteria. If it's relevant, my current one is at will. And I appreciate any input.

Comment: Aside from your poor judgement in this situation, you're essentially asking us which toppings you should get on your pizza. Pros, Cons, etc., etc. Those are all subjective. What is a Pro to you may be a Con to someone else, and vice versa. Choose the one that you're most comfortable with.

Comment: "**Any criteria I should also consider aside from the cost of living, training process, neighborhood, and available connections?**" - Have you compared the career goals and long term growth (for you) when working for either A or B ? How about work-life balance between A & B from reviews of current and former workers from website such as glassdoor.com ? Do you enjoy working with the tech stack from A or B better ? Which company is more stable financially and grow faster in the industry ?

Comment: "Burnt out with the 2-hour commute daily." - I thought you were only 20 miles away? How is it taking 2 hours to drive 20 miles? As for hurting your career, you accepted two job offers, that likely is going to hurt your career.

Comment: @Donald It's approximately 2-hour back and forth. I thought like you too until I actually started working and realize I didn't take into account the rush-hour traffic in a metropolitan area

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Thank you. I think you answered one of the key factors I struggled with during making the decision and helped clear my cluttered head a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I quit, can job A sue me or do anything to me if I leave on extremely short notice?

That depends on the contract and your local labor laws.

> Will it affect my career

Yes. Accepting two offers is very much frowned upon. You have made at least one promise that you are not planning on keeping.

> (I don’t plan to put it on my resume if I quit after a few months, but background checks can find out)?

Omitting it on the resume is dicey. The expectation is that you put all your work experience on there. Background checks can indeed find this out and lying or omitting will not only cost you the job, it will seriously damage your reputation.

> If I stay, what should I do with B since I delayed one month already? That will leave a bad reputation?

It certainly will. You behaved badly and that does indeed damage your reputation. Not much you can do about it at this point: the damage is already done.

> Are there any other risks overall? I know words fly around.

You are at risk of getting a reputation as someone who is shifty and dishonest. Frankly, if I were to find out as a hiring manager, I would put you on the "do not hire" list.

The best you can do, is to make a decision right away and than profusely apologize to the other company.

Comment: Appreciate your honest reply. It was very unprofessional, and I expect to have a terrible reputation on either A or B, but that aside, I'm trying to reduce the damage as much as possible. Regarding the risks, I mean legal risks as it's my biggest concern (and long-term risks for a job search in the general tech market). My current job is full-time at will.

Comment: Read your contract. Make sure you do what it says you are required to do. In most at-will states the notice period is a courtesy but not legally required. However this can be superseded by your employment contract.

Answer (score 0):

#### Grow up and make a decision

We can't tell you what job is better or what you should do.  Things like this aren't done by formulae.  While you're deciding you should also decide if you will be a person of integrity or duplicity.  I leave to you which is better.